# Running desktop application with different user credentials - Winium Automation

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I came across a situation where i need to open the desktop application with different user rather than current windows user.

Now to launch the application am using below code ,

```
  DesktopOptions dop = new DesktopOptions();
          dop.setApplicationPath("Path to executable file");
          WiniumDriver d = new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), dop);
```

but by default the application opens with current windows user , instead i want to open with different user.

FYI , this can be done manually by Shift+Right Click and click on Run with different user option.

Can any one suggest how can i do this with Winium please ?

Comment: you're aware you shared nothing about how the application gets the authenticated user information?

Comment: Thanks Stultuske for quick reply , as per my knowledge application is getting user information through sql server it self ! , i did one thing just now , used RunAs command by giving different credentials  and created a shortcut on desktop , gave the desktop path in set application path. It worked !!

Comment: you let the authentication of an application you wrote yourself be handled by sql server?

Comment: No.. actually i don't have write permissions for the SQL server , it's long process to get the access to that db